# Facebook Instant Games: some accounts return error:CLIENT_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION when called purchaseAsync()

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

In the Facebook web version, some accounts will return an error when calling purchaseAsync (): CLIENT_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, but some accounts can be successfully called without returning an error. What is the reason and how to solve it, thank you very much. (The account that returns an error in the web version can successfully call purchaseAsync () in the facebook android version without returning an error)

sdk url: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.2.js